# Ruby: detect unused/unassigned expressions

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

In ruby, how can I detect unused/unassigned expressions and do something with them like this:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name

    #if a new instantiation of this class is not assigned to anything
    #or used by a calling method, then make a variable called #{name}
    #and assign it to this new instantiation
    if not assigned_or_used
      global_variable_set(name, this)
    end
  end

  def to_s
    "Hi from #{name}"
  end
end
```

Now I want to instantiate a Thing without explicitly assigning it to a variable, but rather have a variable assigned to it automatically when it is instantiated:

```
bob = Thing.new("bob")
puts bob
#=> "Hi from bob"
#works ordinarily

Thing.new("fred")
puts fred
#=> "Hi from fred"
#works after implementing the code for instantiation of Thing
#without explicit assignment/use by a method
```

Comment: Is a singleton what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

Yeesh, I don't know. I could be misunderstanding, but this sounds like a **really bad idea** (maybe you can provide a specific example of *why* you want to do this).

Questions that come to mind:

- Are you just trying to save keystrokes?
- What if there's a name conflict (you make two calls to `Thing.new("fred")` in a row) - what happens to the variable?
- Do you really want to do this, and do you really want to create a global variable on top of it, stripping away all scope safety?
- If this is even possible, can you dig into the garbage collector to do this?

The garbage collector automatically (but only periodically) frees memory when no references exist to an object. Seems like if you did this (creating variables for ALL "Things" unassigned) that you'd be creating a memory leak, and going around the garbage collector's purpose in life. You'd also possibly be fighting the garbage collector - meaning, right after you create an object, if the garbage collector runs between then, and when the variable is created, you'd lose the object anyway.

Comment: I guess messing with the way the garbage collector works is not the way to achieve the goals of the OP.

Comment: I think it's actually a very interesting question nonetheless. Out of curiosity, what was your original aim?